# Postgres remove backslash in jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a jsonb field (let's call it "info") has value like this

```
{"a": "foo", "c": "{ \"d\": \"dog\"}", \"b\": \"bark\"}
```

Using Postgres how do I remove the backslashes?
I tried using

```
REPLACE(info::text, '\', '')
```

or this
    REGEXP_REPLACE(info::text, '\', '')

Either of them works.

Could someone please help..

Comment: Is this json/jsonb? Why do you need remove \?

Comment: \" used because this is the quoting in the string - "c": "{ \"d\": \"dog\"}". May be you need just object "c":  { "d": "dog"} ?

Comment: This was a result of a json manipulation. Yes. particularly, 
here is the code:
create or replace function update_info(info jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select json_object(
        array_agg(key), 
        array_agg(
            case key when 'b' then lower(value)
            else value end))::jsonb
    from jsonb_each_text(info)
$$;

Comment: I originally tried to just lower case a property inside this jsonb field like this ---{"a":"foo", "b":"BARK", "c" :{ "d": "dog"}}. So, thanks to other brilliant people who helped me with this function and I got close to it. but after running this script, I ended up with backslashes in the jsonb.

Answer (score 1):

Query to lowerise jsonb:

```
WITH RECURSIVE z3 AS (
     WITH z2 AS (
          WITH RECURSIVE z AS (
               WITH x AS (
                   -- just your variable
                   SELECT '{"a":"foo", "b":"BARK", "c" :{ "d": "dog"}}'::jsonb AS j
               ) SELECT j,
                        ARRAY [ a ] AS a
                 FROM (
                        SELECT j,
                               jsonb_object_keys(j) AS a
                          FROM x
                      ) AS a
                 UNION ALL SELECT j,
                        a || b
                  FROM (
                        SELECT j,
                               a,
                               jsonb_object_keys(j#>(a)) AS b
                          FROM z
                         WHERE j#>>(a) ~ '^\{.*\}$'
                       ) AS A
           ) SELECT *,
                    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY a) AS i
               FROM z
              WHERE NOT j#>>(a) ~ '^\{.*\}$'
       ) SELECT i,
                jsonb_set(j, a, to_jsonb(lower(j#>>(a)))) AS j
           FROM (
                  SELECT * FROM z2 ORDER BY i LIMIT 1
                ) AS a
        UNION ALL SELECT z2.i,
                jsonb_set(z3.j,
                z2.a,
                to_jsonb(lower(z3.j#>>(z2.a))))
           FROM z3
           JOIN z2 ON (z2.i = z3.i + 1)
  ) SELECT j FROM z3 ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Some explanation:
z CTE looks for all string in jsonb object. 'a' is path to json string. Output:

```
                      j                       |   a   | dense_rank 
----------------------------------------------+-------+------------
 {"a": "foo", "b": "BARK", "c": {"d": "dog"}} | {a}   |          1
 {"a": "foo", "b": "BARK", "c": {"d": "dog"}} | {b}   |          2
 {"a": "foo", "b": "BARK", "c": {"d": "dog"}} | {c,d} |          3
(3 rows)
```

z3 and dense_rank is used to one per select (recursion call) apply lower to json.